# Are there any benefits of encrypting columns with sensitive data in the AWS RDS that is encrypted at rest?

Tags: encryption, appsec, databases

For example, I have an application that allows users to integrate with 3rd party apps. It stores API keys for those applications in AWS RDS as plain text(a pretty old functionality). From the security standpoint, is it even worth encrypting those fields since? in case of a data breach, DB is encrypted at rest anyway and useless for the attacker?

Answer (score 0):

It could increase security posture if there was an attacker that had access to the running RDS but not the ability to read/use the service where the key is stored (KMS, HSM, etc).  This would depend heavily on access controls being reasonable and in place.

Whether that marginal increase is worth the work/price/whatever is up to the sensitivity of the API keys.